# Regular expression ignoring 9 occurrences of a special character '|'

Tags: regex, symbols

Need regular expression to parse a log line, I have to select data after 10th occurrences of pipe symbol `|`

Sample log line;

```
Info     device  Allow:FWD|TCP|data1|data2|data3|data4|data5|data6|data7|data8|data9|data10|data11|0|1|0|0|0|0||||||
```

I have to select data9 from above log line.

Below is the expression I am using right now, this is for a Java program

Expresssion:

```
\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|
```

selection group 11

Instead of escape character one by one would like to skip/ignore 10 pipe symbols and select `data9`

Comment: [Now you have two problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/20842#20842).

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression to do this?

Comment: In the regex posted "selection group 11" is actually `data10`, not `data9`. (However, it won't actually match at all since you are matching 1 too many pipe symbols, or there is a pipe symbol missing from the "sample log line"?)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's why quantifiers are for.

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){10}([^|]*)
```

Comment: `^(?:.*?\|){10}(.*?)\|` This is cleaner in my view. The questioner says they're using Java and Java totally supports this syntax.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire: Your regex takes [117 steps](https://regex101.com/r/skLgN6/1), mine [37 steps](https://regex101.com/r/D7nwKn/1)

Comment: Wow, first time I hear about "steps". I gotta check that metrics in the future. I still find my regex more "clean", but I totally agree yours might be more efficient.

Comment: `[^|]*` is definitely faster, because there's no possibility of backtracking. I might even use `[^|\n]` in order to ensure the regex doesn't run off the end of a line (e.g. in case a line has less than 10 fields for any reason).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yours looks for at least 10 `|` characters. Toto's looks for exactly 10.

Comment: @CJDennis Though the reluctant quantifiers (*?) will try to get as little characters as possible so it will also only take 10, because there are no other requirements which could fail and cause backtracking aside from there being not enough | characters.

Comment: @Falco Good point! I missed that!

Comment: @nneonneo it only is faster on smart Regex-Engines. The Engine is smart enough to realize `[^|]` and `\|` are exclusive and does not even backtrack one step. A naive engine would backtrack without a match and try each number of less characters to match `[^|]*`

Answer (score 21):

If you're using a regex in the context of another programming language (Python, C#, etc.), that language likely has some type of string splitting function. In my experience, it's usually easier to split on the delimiter and get a list/array of values instead of using regexes to split.

Comment: This is only true of a very simple single character split. The moment you need to do "beginning of the string" or "this character or that character" or "replace with this pattern that is matched" then you get a nightmare with nested array looping logic.

Comment: C# for example both has parameter in split str.Split(new []{'|'}, 10) (alternatively "|".ToCharArray()), and indexing with str.Split('|')[10..] if you want the remainder split too. These solutions will often run faster than a regex, so for simple cases where they can be used it might be a better choice. If course if you need complexity then regex can be better, but for this case split functions may be better suited.

Comment: @Nelson "This is only true of a very simple single character split." - Like the example given in the question.

Comment: In my experience, text parsing always has edge cases that wasn't initially thought of. You don't want to pick a solution where solving edge cases becomes exponentially more difficult.

Comment: In C# there is an overload where a string can be passed as a delimiter, not only a single char: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_